# How do I add MATLAB to the dock?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, matlab, dock

I open MATLAB:

```
$ matlab &
[1] 3099
```

I right-click its new icon on the dock and click 'Lock to Launcher'.

The next time I try to use MATLAB, I click the new dock icon. MATLAB acts like it's succesfully opening (shows the startup graphic briefly, taskbar icon flashes like it's in-progress), but then it stops, apparently automatically terminating.

What's wrong? How do I add MATLAB to dock (so I can merely click an icon instead of opening it from Terminal)?

I suspect what's wrong is that unlike other software with a 'permanent' something (process ID?), MATLAB's something changes each time, and so 'Lock to Launcher' doesn't work to open it each time ...

Comment: Have you tried creating a `.desktop` for MATLAB?

Comment: No. I don't know what a .desktop is nor how to create one, and I suspect the 'matlab' command is a symbolic link (whatever that is) rather than an executable. (How did you format that text, by the way?)

Comment: You can figure that out with `type -a matlab`

Comment: Btw, to format code or similar, surround it with `

Comment: `-a matlab` resulted in `-a: command not found`. What that was supposed to accomplish?
`

Comment: No, you should type `type -a matlab`. The command is called "type"

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. That yields `matlab is /usr/local/bin/matlab`, and, navigating to this folder, I see that matlab is a 'Link to Program', as I suspected. I don't know what to do with this information to create a shortcut to execute the program in Launcher, though.

Answer (score 0):

Create a **matlab.desktop** file in ~/.local/share/applications

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Matlab
Type=Application
Exec=*location to matlab*
Icon=*location to icon (optional)*
Terminal=true
```

You can use `whereis matlab` to find the location to matlab.

The last line is optional, either you have to find a suitable icon for matlab on your computer, or download one and store it where appropriate.

Finally, make it executable with `sudo chmod +x matlab.desktop`, or by right clicking on the file in the file manager, and make it executable under permissions.

Comment: In that folder there already is a file `matlab_r2017b_-_student_use.desktop`, however Right-Click -> Open returns the error message that it's untrusted due to installation from an unknown source. (Apparently doing something with it can execute the command `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB`...) I see the Execute checkbox to mark in Properties > Permissions, and that turned the default Aa icon into the MATLAB logo icon! Then I was able to drag and drop it onto the dock! ... However, the behavior is the same as the OP: It appears to self-terminate. What should I do with this .desktop?

Comment: It turns out you have to add `Terminal=true` to the desktop file to make sure it doesn't self terminate.